# jquery drag drop issue in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop

A simple drag and drop,  three droppable divs each accepts only one draggable element.  Works fin in chrome and safari, but in firefox, when I drag a second element the droppable elements move round the page.  This happens both with simple html and a bootstrap container so I assume the problem is in the jquery but I can't see what it is.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".rect").draggable({revert: 'invalid',  snap: ".dropSnap",
            stack: ".draggable"} );
    
        $("#simpleregular").droppable({
            accept: "#reg",
            //accept: "#cars",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "lightgreen");
                ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'middle bottom', at: 'middle bottom' } );
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "")
            }
        });
    
        $("#presentcontinuous").droppable({
            accept: "#cont",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "lightgreen");
                ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'middle bottom', at: 'middle bottom' } );
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "")
            }
        });
        $("#simplegeneral").droppable({
            accept: "#gen",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "lightgreen");
                ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'middle bottom', at: 'middle bottom' } );
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "")
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.pureexample.com/js/lib/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <div>
    <div>
        <div id="cont" class="rect"><img src="../images/sentence_present_continuous.png" alt="present continuous"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <div id="reg" class="rect"><img src="../images/sentence_simple_regular.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="gen" class="rect"><img src="../images/sentence_simple_general.png"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
    <div>
        <div id="presentcontinuous" class="squaredotted"><img src="../images/present_continuous.png" alt="present continuous"></div>
        <div id="continuous"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="simpleregular" class="squaredotted"><img src="../images/simple_present_regular.png" alt="simple regular"></div>
        <div id="regular"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="simplegeneral" class="squaredotted"><img src="../images/simple_present_general.png" alt="simple general"></div>
        <div id="general"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

```
    #container {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

.navbar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /*background: transparent; */
    border-color: black;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.active {
    background: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.7);
}

.active a {
    color: black;

}

.navbar-default a {

    color: #ffffff;
}

#navDiv {
    background: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.5);
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

#navDiv a {
    background: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.5);
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: white;
}

#navDiv a:hover {
    color: #4DBBDB;
}

#navDiv a:active {
    color: blue;
}

.menu ul li a {
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(4, 1, 7, 0.5);
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 14px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: white;
}

/*text-shadow: #eee 0px 0px 2px; } */

.menu ul li a:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px #756377;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px #777;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 14px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: white;
}

hr {
    display: block;
}

.reveal {
    display: none;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

span.highlighted {
    background-color: pink;
}

span.highlighted2 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    color: white;
}

span.highlighted3 {
    background-color: cyan;
}

span.highlighted4 {
    background-color: dimgrey;
    color: white;
}

.peekaboo {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.answer {
    color: green;
}

.leftPanel {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.rightPanel {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    /*background-color: #9999FF;*/
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.header {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#btn {
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: white; /*Sets the text hover color on navbar*/
}

.nav .navbar-nav > li > a:link, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:link {
    color: white; /*Sets the text  color on navbar*/
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active >
a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: black; /*BACKGROUND color for active*/

}

.navbar-brand > i > a:hover, .navbar-brand .navbar-brand > li > a:focus {
    color: white; /*Sets the text hover color on navbar*/
}

.whitelink a:link {
    color: white;
}

span.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-info-sign {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}


span.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-facetime-video {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-headphones {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-arrow-down {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-question-sign {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-tasks {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-thumbs-up {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-education {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-random {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-sort {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
span.glyphicon-pencil {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.glyphicon-thumbs-up small {
    font-size: 5em;
}

.small {
    font-size: 1em !important;;
}

.list-group-item {
    border: 0;
}

.list-group-item a {
    color: #333333;
}

.list-group-item a:hover {
    color: #4DBBDB;
}

.gap {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#vocab {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.vid {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.truefalse {
    text-align: left;
}

#pics {
    width: 750px;
}

#sentences {
    width: 750px;
}

.sortable-list2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

#sortable-list2 li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

#sortable-list1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
}

#sortable-list1 li {
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

#image-list1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
}

#image-list1 li {
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

#image-list2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
}

#image-list2 li {
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.toggler {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}

#button {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#effect {
    width: 240px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 0.4em;
    position: relative;
}

#effect h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
}

audio {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

iframe {
    border: 0px;
}

#sentences {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 600px;
}

#pics {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 600px;
}

#vocab {
    display:none;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.words {
    text-align: center;
}

#score {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    /*border: 1px solid;*/
}


.black {
    background-color: black;
}

.inverse-dropdown {
    background-color: #222;
    border-color: #080808;
}

li a {
    color: #999;
}
a hover{
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #000;
 }



.rect {
    width: 260px;
    height: 63px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.squaredotted {
    width: 260px;
    height: 275px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.squaredotted img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/40qk9d7n/4/) and it seems to work fine in all browsers. There may be something wrong with `style.css` or `presentAndPresentContinuousDrop.js` that you're including, because those are the only files I cannot include in the fiddle. PS: that UI version is ancient, you should update it if possible ;)

Comment: Thanks, the presentAndPresentContinuousDrop.js is the jquery which is shown here, I should have been clearer.  I want to add the css but can't see how to add code in the edit screen, I'm quite new here

Comment: seems there was an edit pending, I've now been able to add the css, thanks for the help

Comment: I've edited your question to use Code Snippet. Now you can add the CSS to that code snippet. Also you should mention specific issue in the title instead of generic statement. (I've edited that too)

Answer (score 0):

so after some experiments and some googling I found that rather than put the draggables in divs I'd be better using list items and leaving the droppables in divs. I guess some browsers are just more tolerant.  The draggables now look like :

```
  <ul>
                <li id="cont" class="rect"><img src="../../images/sentence_present_continuous.png" alt="present continuous"></li>
                <li id="reg" class="rect"><img src="../../images/sentence_simple_regular.png"></li>
                <li id="gen" class="rect"><img src="../../images/sentence_simple_general.png"></li>
            </ul>
```

job done